# How to make Facebook og tags dynamic in angular2 application?

Tags: javascript, facebook, angular, meta-tags

I have a application similar to quora. when i share that question i want that corresponding image and content has to be shown in share popup.

usually facebook og tags has to be added in header. using javascript i cannot access tags in header and manipulate the content of og tags. any way to achieve this.

i tried ng2-meta it didn't helped.

Answer (score 1):

I think `Meta` service can help you:

```
import { Meta } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `...`
})
export class AppComponent { 
  constructor(private meta: Meta) {
    meta.addTag({name: 'og:title', content: 'Content Title'});
  }
}
```

See also

- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/platform-browser/index/Meta-class.html

Comment: i didn't see exported member 'Meta' in platform-browser.d.ts,
 platform-browser version - 2.2.3,
 angular version - 2.2.3

Comment: I did not want to update angular right now to 4, currently i'm in 2.2.3